# whereby and in/by which

Tags: grammar

The below is a sentence from my English textbook.

'We need to develop a system whereby workers and management can communicate more effectively.'

And the book shows an alternative using 'in/by which'.

'We need to develop the system in/by which workers and management can communicate more effectively.'

I know general grammatical rule about articles but I can't understand why 'a system' is replaced by 'the system' in the second sentence.

Comment: I think it could be just an error.

Comment: Probably just a simple error. Incidentally, "Whereby" means "by which", not "in which", so there's another error in your book.

Comment: Both sentences are fine. I agree that it's inconsistent to replace *a* with *the*. While it's not wrong, it detracts from the discussion of *whereby*. (But I disagree with a previous comment that *whereby* cannot mean *in which*. If you replace it with *in which*, the sentences remains grammatical—and could be interpreted the same way, so that statement is wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same book as you, and I have to say that in the second sentence you can use the article that you want to. It doesn't matter if you say "a system" or "the system". Both articles are correct in either sentence.

Comment: "We need to develop a system..." allows for more than one. "We need to develop the system..." implies that there is only one system that will meet these requirements. They do not mean the same thing.